# PyArmor - Pack to one single executable

Tags: python, pyarmor

Hi using PyArmor when I do this command:

`pyarmor pack main.py`

It packs it into a folder called `dist` and inside contains my .exe along with a lot of Python Extention Files..

I understand that PyArmor uses PyInstaller to pack its files. And PyInstaller has an option called `--onefile`.

How can I pack my obfuscated script to one single .exe file?

Maybe something like... `pyarmor pack --onefile main.py` ??

Answer (score 21):

```
pyarmor pack --clean -e "--onefile " main.py
```

don't forget about whitespace in "-e"

should do the fix :)